# Spring boot path param url encoding issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, urlencode, path-variables

I have a spring boot application, where in one of my controller i have a string coming from path parameter. I have my controller like below:

Controller.java

```
@GetMapping(value=“/id/{txt}/user”)
public ResponseEntity<MyUser> getUser(@PathVariable String txt) {

}
```

In my requests i will have the txt value as a string with some of the url encoded characters. Below is the example that the request has:

```
/id/Siney6jginshbnsu%252Fghshs%253D
```

But when i debug the application the path variable txt  is coming as :

```
/id/Siney6jginshbnsu%2Fghshs%3D
```

The problem is i am doing a string comparison for txt using .equals and because of the above encoding/decoding issue, i am seeing the issue.

Is there any way that i can get the url encoded string from request completely as is?

I know i can try to encode the txt which adds %25 but the problem is i might have % in the string which will encode it as %25.  So appreciate if any one can help or suggest a way to fix this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code:

```
@GetMapping(value=“/id/{txt}/user”)
public ResponseEntity<MyUser> getUser(@PathVariable("txt") String txt) {

}
```

Comment: Other codes..not sure what exactly do you mean..i can definitely try to add more information if needed but can you please clarify me on what other codes do you want me to include ?

Comment: Its a spring boot application, with the controller as already mentioned in the question. The problem is spring is urldecoding the pathparam.

Answer (score 0):

```
@GetMapping("/id/{txt}/user")
public ResponseEntity<MyUser> getUser(HttpServletRequest request, @PathVariable(name="txt") String txt) {
    String urlNotEncoded = request.getRequestURI();
    ...
}
```

In this way urlNotEncoded contains: "/id/Siney6jginshbnsu%252Fghshs%253D/user" and at his point you can create your own function to extract the txt.

Comment: This looks like a good alternative. But do you think is it a good practice to go with this approach? As spring has the functionality to do the same, shouldwe really handle this externally? Does spring have anything like grabbing the complete things as a string?

Comment: As far as I know because PathVariable is extracting values from the URI path, it’s not encoded. On the other hand, RequestParam is encoded (but I don't think you can use this approach). Probably the best thing to do is avoiding special character that need to be encoded in the {txt} part. I assume is an ID so you should change the way you generete it.